# Check the differences in a vector and select the ones that provide positive output

Tags: r, vector, filter, filtering

I need to check the differences (p_k - (p_k-1)) and select the ones that provide positive result, e.g.

```
7-5 = 2 (positive)
8-7 = 1 (positive)
6-8 = -2 (negative: cut it off)
etc.
```

I use the following data:

```
p <- c(5,7,8,6,5,7,12)
```

This is what I tried, but it provides logical true/false outputs (not numeric):

```
result <- diff(p)>0
```

Comment: `diff(p)[diff(p)>0]`?

Answer (score 0):

if your looking for the values {k} such that (p_k > p_(k-1), then you want

```
result = which(diff(p)>0) + 1
```

(The `+ 1` is because in your notation k is the larger of the pair [k, k -1])